# Ethernet link is down

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet

My Ubuntu 20.04 laptop can connect through wireless but not wired. `ip link` shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:5a:0f:d8:0a:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:85:00:b5:6d:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I tried `sudo ip link set up dev enp0s31f6` but the link remained down.

`lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` gives:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-V      [8086:1570] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet Connection I219-V [103c:8079]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

`dmesg|grep e1000e` gives:

```
[    4.095621] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    4.095622] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    4.095640] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.096716] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    4.339134] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    4.411453] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 70:5a:0f:d8:0a:f7
[    4.411455] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    4.411521] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    4.429803] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
[ 2049.084704] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
```

What is a possible solution?

Comment: I hate to say it, but I too have an HP laptop and it has the same issue.  Mine is a Pavilion DV7-3000.  The link lights come on, but not showing any connection either in Windows or in Ubuntu.  I am looking at replacing the ethernet port to the NIC again on it.  I don't know what it is about these ones, but the connection isn't good at all.  :(

Comment: @Terrance You said you will have to replace it "again"? So it's been broken one or many times before?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yep.  It used to belong to a co-worker of mine and it was broken before, but nothing you could see physically.  I tested it every which way I knew of and determined that the port itself was bad.  I purchased a new port on eBay and replaced it.  It actually worked after that just fine for a few years, and now it is out again.  I inherited this laptop from my friend's widow after he passed away from pancreatic cancer, so this laptop actually means a lot to me.

Comment: may we also see: `dmesg | grep enp`

Answer (score 1):

This particular network device has a history of throwing errors at boot time that Windows ignores and Linux pays attention to. That said, it can generally be fixed with the latest driver from Intel, though it does require a bit more effort.

Try this:

1. Download [the latest driver from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCI-E-Gigabit-Network-Connections-under-Linux-?product=71307) (Version 3.8.4 as of this answer)
2. Extract the files and change to the `src` directory:
   `cd e1000e-3.8.4/src/`
3. Remove any existing e1000e drivers from the kernel:
   `sudo rmmod e1000e`
4. Compile the driver module:
   `sudo make install`
5. Load the module using modprobe:
   `sudo modprobe e1000e`

The output will be written to `/lib/modules/updates/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko`. At this point you can test your network by accessing a website or pinging another machine on your network. So long as everything is good, you can make the change permanent with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-$(uname -r)
update-initramfs -u
```

Hope this helps.